# Cuda detected version in Hugging Face (HF) is 5.4.0 while it's recommended to be 5.5.0, but pytorch & nvidia-smi say it's higher, how to fix?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I get:

```py
Detected kernel version 5.4.0, which is below the recommended minimum of 5.5.0; this can cause the process to hang. It is recommended to upgrade the kernel to the minimum version or higher.
```

but my cuda seems fine:

```
Model is currently on: next(iter(model.parameters())).device=device(type='cuda', index=0)
Model is currently on: next(iter(model.parameters())).dtype=torch.bfloat16
vocab_size: len(tokenizer)=32000 
Expected random loss: math.log(len(tokenizer))=10.373491181781864
CUDA version: torch.version.cuda='12.1
```

and nvidia:

```bash
(base) brando9@ampere8~ $ python -c "import torch; print(torch.randn(2, 4).to('cuda') @ torch.randn(4, 1).to('cuda'));"
tensor([[-2.4671],
        [-0.6787]], device='cuda:0')
(base) brando9@ampere8~ $ nvidia-smi
Fri Jan 26 16:58:00 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.54.03              Driver Version: 535.54.03    CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:07:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   64C    P0             385W / 400W |  10822MiB / 81920MiB |     99%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   53C    P0             364W / 400W |  10399MiB / 81920MiB |     99%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:44:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   51C    P0             274W / 400W |  53285MiB / 81920MiB |     60%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:4A:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   55C    P0             310W / 400W |  53283MiB / 81920MiB |    100%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   48C    P0             103W / 400W |  52889MiB / 81920MiB |    100%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:8A:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0              64W / 400W |    873MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:C0:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0              60W / 400W |      7MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:C3:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   64C    P0             372W / 400W |  61557MiB / 81920MiB |    100%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A   1773004      C   python                                    10386MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A   3303288      C   ...ihan/miniconda3/envs/rdb/bin/python      416MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A   1773467      C   python                                    10386MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A   1718375      C   python                                    53270MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A   1718924      C   python                                    53268MiB |
|    4   N/A  N/A   1677419      C   python                                    52874MiB |
|    5   N/A  N/A   1768821      C   ...iconda/envs/beyond_scale/bin/python      748MiB |
|    7   N/A  N/A    459941      C   python                                    61542MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
n(base) brando9@ampere8~ $ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_May__3_18:49:52_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0
```

Seem fine.

what is going on? How do I fix this? Is there anything to fix?

Code:

```py
"""
Goal: making HF training script for model (e.g., llama v2) using raw text of informal and formal mathematics (unpaired data).

Inspiration:
- ref: SO accelerate + trainer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76675018/how-does-one-use-accelerate-with-the-hugging-face-hf-trainer
- ref: The unreasonable effectiveness of few-shot learning for machine translation https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.01398
- ref: colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1io951Ex17-6OUaogCo7OiR-eXga_oUOH?usp=sharing
- ref: SO on collate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879872/how-to-use-huggingface-hf-trainer-train-with-custom-collate-function/76929999#76929999

Looks very useful especially for peft:
- peft https://github.com/huggingface/trl/blob/main/examples/scripts/sft_trainer.py

python trl/examples/scripts/sft_trainer.py \
    --model_name meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf \
    --dataset_name timdettmers/openassistant-guanaco \
    --load_in_4bit \
    --use_peft \
    --batch_size 4 \
    --gradient_accumulation_steps 2

- qlora https://github.com/artidoro/qlora/blob/main/scripts/finetune_llama2_guanaco_7b.sh, 
- https://github.com/artidoro/qlora/blob/main/qlora.py

export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=6
"""
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Callable
import datasets
from datasets import load_dataset, interleave_datasets
import torch
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, PreTrainedTokenizer, AutoTokenizer, Trainer, TrainingArguments, AutoConfig
import math

import sys
from training.reinit_and_smaller_llama2 import get_deafult_smallest_baby_llama2_v1_36m_0p036b, get_weight_norms, reinitialize_weights_gpt_neox_20B_inspired_4_llama2
sys.path = [''] + sys.path
from training.utils import eval_hf, eval_hf_with_subsample, get_column_names, get_data_from_hf_dataset, group_texts, raw_dataset_2_lm_data

# -- Experiments 

def train():
    """
    I decided to make the string data close to context length of llama2 7B 4096 tokens.
    So if any string is shorter, the tokenize will padd it according to Claude.
    
    """
    # feel free to move the import statements if you want, sometimes I like everything in one place so I can easily copy-paste it into a script
    import datetime
    from pathlib import Path
    import datasets
    from datasets import load_dataset, interleave_datasets
    import torch
    import transformers
    from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizer
    from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, PreTrainedTokenizer, AutoTokenizer, Trainer, TrainingArguments, AutoConfig
    import random
    import math
    import os
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    # buffer_size = 500_000  # can't remember what this was for and doesn't seem to be anywhere
    probabilities = []
    data_mixture_name = None
    streaming = True
    data_files = [None]
    seed = 0
    split = 'train'
    max_length = 1024  # gpt2 context length
    shuffle = False
    report_to = 'none'  # safest default
    # CHUNK_SIZE = 16_896  # approximately trying to fill the llama2 context length of 4096
    batch_size = 2
    gradient_accumulation_steps = 2
    num_epochs = 1
    num_tokens_trained = None
    num_batches=1
    optim='paged_adamw_32bit'
    learning_rate=1e-5
    warmup_ratio=0.01
    weight_decay=0.01
    lr_scheduler_type='constant_with_warmup'
    # lr_scheduler_kwargs={}

    # -- Setup wandb
    import wandb
    # - Dryrun
    mode = 'dryrun'; seed = 0; report_to = 'none'

    # - Online (real experiment)
    # mode = 'online'; seed = 0; report_to = 'wandb'

    # - train data sets
    # path, name, data_files, split = ['c4'], ['en'], [None], ['train']
    path, name, data_files, split = ['UDACA/PileSubsets'], ['uspto'], [None], ['train']
    # path, name, data_files, split = ['UDACA/PileSubsets'], ['pubmed'], [None], ['train']
    # path, name, data_files, split = ['UDACA/PileSubsets', 'UDACA/PileSubsets'], ['uspto', 'pubmed'], [None, None], ['train', 'train']
    # - models
    # pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'gpt2'  # this is the smallest model gpt2, 124M params https://huggingface.co/gpt2 
    # pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf'
    # pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf'
    # pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-hf'
    # pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-70b-hf'
    # pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1'
    pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'baby_llama2_v1'
    # - important training details or it wont run, mem issues maybe
    max_steps = 1
    # max_steps = 300
    # max_steps = 19_073 # <- CHANGE THIS  11 days with baby llama2 v1 36m 1, 32
    # max_steps = 866 # <- CHANGE THIS 12hs with with baby llama2 v1 36m 1, 32
    # max_steps = 1_761 # <- CHANGE THIS 12hs with with baby llama2 v1 36m 5, 6 0.2168M tokens
    # max_steps = 306_000 # <- CHANGE THIS 12hs with with baby llama2 v1 36m 1, 32 35.1 tokens
    # max_length = 4096
    max_length = 1024
    num_batches=1
    # single gpu
    # batch_size, gradient_accumulation_steps = 1, 32  # e.g., choosing large number mabe for stability of training? 4 (per_device_train_batch_size) * 8 (gradient_accumulation_steps), based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca 
    # batch_size, gradient_accumulation_steps = 6, 5  # e.g., choosing large number mabe for stability of training? 4 (per_device_train_batch_size) * 8 (gradient_accumulation_steps), based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca 
    # batch_size, gradient_accumulation_steps = 5, 6  # e.g., choosing large number mabe for stability of training? 4 (per_device_train_batch_size) * 8 (gradient_accumulation_steps), based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca 
    # batch_size, gradient_accumulation_steps = 4, 6  # e.g., choosing large number mabe for stability of training? 4 (per_device_train_batch_size) * 8 (gradient_accumulation_steps), based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca 
    # batch_size, gradient_accumulation_steps = 4, 8  # e.g., choosing large number mabe for stability of training? 4 (per_device_train_batch_size) * 8 (gradient_accumulation_steps), based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca 
    learning_rate=1e-4
    # learning_rate=1e-5
    optim='paged_adamw_32bit'
    # optim = 'adafactor'
    weight_decay=0.1
    warmup_ratio=0.01
    lr_scheduler_type='cosine'
    # lr_scheduler_type='constant_with_warmup'
    # lr_scheduler_type='cosine_with_warmup'
    # lr_scheduler_kwargs={},  # ref: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.37.0/en/main_classes/optimizer_schedules#transformers.SchedulerType 
    # -- multiple gpus 3 4096 context len
    # batch_size, gradient_accumulation_steps = 4, 8  # e.g., choosing large number mabe for stability of training? 4 (per_device_train_batch_size) * 8 (gradient_accumulation_steps), based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca 
    # gradient_checkpointing = False
    gradient_checkpointing = True
    print(f'{batch_size=} {gradient_accumulation_steps=} {gradient_checkpointing=} {num_epochs=}')
    # -- wandb
    num_tokens_trained = max_steps * batch_size * max_length * num_batches 
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-m%m-d%d-t%Hh_%Mm_%Ss')
    run_name = f'beyond scale: {path} ({today=} ({name=}) {data_mixture_name=} {probabilities=} {pretrained_model_name_or_path=} {data_files=} {max_steps=} {batch_size=} {num_tokens_trained=} {gradient_accumulation_steps=} {optim=} {learning_rate=} {max_length=} {weight_decay=} {warmup_ratio=})'
    print(f'\n---> {run_name=}\n')

    # - Init wandb
    debug: bool = mode == 'dryrun'  # BOOL, debug?
    run = wandb.init(mode=mode, project="beyond-scale", name=run_name, save_code=True)
    wandb.config.update({"path": path, "name": name, "today": today, 'probabilities': probabilities, 'batch_size': batch_size, 'debug': debug, 'data_mixture_name': data_mixture_name, 'streaming': streaming, 'data_files': data_files, 'seed': seed, 'pretrained_model_name_or_path': pretrained_model_name_or_path, 'num_epochs': num_epochs, 'gradient_accumulation_steps': gradient_accumulation_steps})
    # run.notify_on_failure() # https://community.wandb.ai/t/how-do-i-set-the-wandb-alert-programatically-for-my-current-run/4891
    output_dir = Path(f'~/data/results_{today}/').expanduser() if not debug else Path(f'~/data/results/').expanduser()
    print(f'{output_dir=}')
    print(f'{debug=}')
    print(f'{wandb.config=}')

    # -- Load model and tokenizer  
    print(f'{pretrained_model_name_or_path=}')
    if pretrained_model_name_or_path == 'gpt2':
        from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel
        tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path)
        if tokenizer.pad_token_id is None:
            tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
            print(f'{tokenizer.pad_token=}')
        print(f'{tokenizer.eos_token=}')
        print(f'{tokenizer.eos_token_id=}')
        model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path)
        device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        model = model.to(device)
        block_size: int = tokenizer.model_max_length
        print(f'{block_size=}')
        print()
    elif 'Llama-2' in pretrained_model_name_or_path or 'Mistral' in pretrained_model_name_or_path:
        # - llama2
        from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, BitsAndBytesConfig, AutoTokenizer
        # bf16 or fp32
        torch_dtype = torch.bfloat16 if torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8 else torch.float32 # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32
        # get model
        model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
            pretrained_model_name_or_path,
            # quantization_config=quantization_config,
            # device_map=device_map,  # device_map = None  https://github.com/huggingface/trl/blob/01c4a35928f41ba25b1d0032a085519b8065c843/examples/scripts/sft_trainer.py#L82
            trust_remote_code=True,
            torch_dtype=torch_dtype,
            use_auth_token=True,
        )
        # https://github.com/artidoro/qlora/blob/7f4e95a68dc076bea9b3a413d2b512eca6d004e5/qlora.py#L347C13-L347C13
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
            pretrained_model_name_or_path,
            # cache_dir=args.cache_dir,
            padding_side="right",
            use_fast=False, # Fast tokenizer giving issues.
            # tokenizer_type='llama' if 'llama' in args.model_name_or_path else None, # Needed for HF name change
            # tokenizer_type='llama',
            trust_remote_code=True,
            use_auth_token=True,
            # token=token,  # load from cat keys/brandos_hf_token.txt if you want to load it in python and not run huggingface-cli login
        )
        # - Ensure padding token is set TODO: how does this not screw up the fine-tuning? e.g., now model doesn't learn to predict eos since it's padded our by mask, ref: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/why-does-the-falcon-qlora-tutorial-code-use-eos-token-as-pad-token/45954
        if tokenizer.pad_token_id is None:
            tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
            print(f'{tokenizer.pad_token=}')
        print(f'{tokenizer.eos_token=}')
        print(f'{ tokenizer.eos_token_id=}')
        # get context length for setting max length for training
        if hasattr(model.config, "context_length"):
            print("Context length:", model.config.context_length)
            max_length = model.config.context_length
        else:
            # CHUNK_SIZE = 16_896  # approximately trying to fill the llama2 context length of 4096
            max_length = 4096
        block_size: int = 4096
        print(f'{block_size=}')
    elif 'baby_llama2_v1' in pretrained_model_name_or_path:
        model = get_deafult_smallest_baby_llama2_v1_36m_0p036b()
        reinitialize_weights_gpt_neox_20B_inspired_4_llama2(model, L=max_length)
        # export HF_TOKEN=$(cat ~/keys/brandos_hf_token.txt)
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf', padding_side="right", use_fast=False, trust_remote_code=True, use_auth_token=True)
        device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        model = model.to(device)
        torch_dtype = torch.bfloat16 if torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8 else torch.float32 # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32
        model = model.to(torch_dtype)
        block_size: int = max_length
        print(f'{block_size=}')
    print("Number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters()))
    print(f"Total weight norm: {get_weight_norms(model)=}")
    print(f'{torch.cuda.device_count()=} (makes sure GPUs are visible and accesible to Pytorch.)')
    print(f'Model is currently on: {next(iter(model.parameters())).device=}')
    print(f'Model is currently on: {next(iter(model.parameters())).dtype=}')
    # Sanity check -- is loss random? lnV = -ln(1/V) = -ln(1/50257) = 10.82 since CE = avg_i v_i * ln(1/p_i) but only one token is right so vi = 1 for some i so CE = ln(1/p_i)
    print(f'vocab_size: {len(tokenizer)=} \nExpected random loss: {math.log(len(tokenizer))=}')
    print(f"CUDA version: {torch.version.cuda=}")
    eval_hf_with_subsample('UDACA/pile_openwebtext2', None, 'validation', model, tokenizer, block_size, output_dir, max_eval_samples=2, print_str='> Eval OpenWebtext rand mdl')
    eval_hf_with_subsample('c4', 'en', 'validation', model, tokenizer, block_size, output_dir, max_eval_samples=2, print_str='> Eval C4 rand mdl')
    
    # --- Load datasets
    # -- Get train data set
    # - Load interleaved combined datasets
    train_datasets = [load_dataset(path, name, data_files=data_file, streaming=streaming, split=split).with_format("torch") for path, name, data_file, split in zip(path, name, data_files, split)]
    probabilities = [1.0/len(train_datasets) for _ in train_datasets]  
    # - Get raw train data set
    raw_train_datasets = interleave_datasets(train_datasets, probabilities)
    remove_columns = get_column_names(raw_train_datasets)  # remove all keys that are not tensors to avoid bugs in collate function in task2vec's pytorch data loader
    # - Get tokenized train data set
    # Note: Setting `batched=True` in the `dataset.map` function of Hugging Face's datasets library processes the data in batches rather than one item at a time, significantly speeding up the tokenization and preprocessing steps.
    tokenize_function = lambda examples: tokenizer(examples["text"])
    tokenized_train_datasets = raw_train_datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns)
    _group_texts = lambda examples : group_texts(examples, block_size)
    # - Get actual data set for lm training (in this case each seq is of length block_size, no need to worry about pad = eos since we are filling each sequence)
    lm_train_dataset = tokenized_train_datasets.map(_group_texts, batched=True)
    batch = get_data_from_hf_dataset(lm_train_dataset, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size)
    print(f'{len(next(iter(batch))["input_ids"])=}')
    assert all(len(data_dict['input_ids']) == block_size for data_dict in iter(batch)), f'Error, some seq in batch are not of length {block_size}'
    train_dataset = lm_train_dataset

    # -- max steps manually decided depending on how many tokens we want to train on
    per_device_train_batch_size = batch_size
    print(f'{per_device_train_batch_size=}')
    print(f'{num_epochs=} {max_steps=}')

    # -- Training arguments and trainer instantiation ref: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.31.0/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments
    print(f'{output_dir=}')
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=output_dir,  # The output directory where the model predictions and checkpoints will be written.
        # output_dir='.',  # The output directory where the model predictions and checkpoints will be written.
        max_steps=max_steps,  # TODO: hard to fix, see above
        per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,  # based on alpaca https://github.com/tatsu-lab/stanford_alpaca, allows to process effective_batch_size = gradient_accumulation_steps * batch_size, num its to accumulate before opt update step
        gradient_checkpointing = gradient_checkpointing,  # TODO depending on hardware set to true?
        optim=optim,
        # warmup_steps=int(max_steps*warmup_ratio),  # TODO: once real training starts we can select this number for llama v2, what does llama v2 do to make it stable while v1 didn't?
        warmup_ratio=warmup_ratio,  # copying alpaca for now, number of steps for a linear warmup, TODO once real training starts change? 
        # weight_decay=0.01,  # TODO once real training change?
        weight_decay=weight_decay,  # TODO once real training change?
        learning_rate = learning_rate,  # TODO once real training change? anything larger than -3 I've had terrible experiences with
        max_grad_norm=1.0, # TODO once real training change?
        lr_scheduler_type=lr_scheduler_type,  # TODO once real training change? using what I've seen most in vision 
        # lr_scheduler_kwargs=lr_scheduler_kwargs,  # ref: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.37.0/en/main_classes/optimizer_schedules#transformers.SchedulerType 
        logging_dir=Path('~/data/maf/logs').expanduser(),
        # save_steps=4000,  # alpaca does 2000, other defaults were 500
        save_steps=max_steps//3,  # alpaca does 2000, other defaults were 500
        # save_steps=1,  # alpaca does 2000, other defaults were 500
        # logging_steps=250,
        # logging_steps=50,  
        logging_first_step=True,
        # logging_steps=3,
        logging_steps=1,
        remove_unused_columns=False,  # TODO don't get why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879872/how-to-use-huggingface-hf-trainer-train-with-custom-collate-function/76929999#76929999 , https://claude.ai/chat/475a4638-cee3-4ce0-af64-c8b8d1dc0d90
        report_to=report_to,  # change to wandb!
        fp16=False,  # never ever set to True
        bf16=torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8,  # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32
    )
    print(f'{pretrained_model_name_or_path=}\n{optim=}\n{learning_rate=}')

    # -- Init Trainer
    print(f'{train_dataset=}')
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,  
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
    )

    # - Train
    cuda_visible_devices = os.environ.get('CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES')
    if cuda_visible_devices is not None:
        print(f"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = {cuda_visible_devices}")
    trainer.train()
    trainer.save_model(output_dir=output_dir)  # TODO is this really needed? https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/do-we-need-to-explicity-save-the-model-if-the-save-steps-is-not-a-multiple-of-the-num-steps-with-hf/56745

    # -- Evaluation, NOTE: we are evaluating at the end not during training
    print()
    # - Evaluate model on OpenWebtext
    print('---- Evaluate model on OpenWebtext')
    metrics = eval_hf_with_subsample('UDACA/pile_openwebtext2', None, 'validation', model, tokenizer, block_size, output_dir)
    print(f'{metrics=}')
    # - Evaluate on C4
    print('---- Evaluate model on C4')
    metrics = eval_hf_with_subsample('c4', 'en', 'validation', model, tokenizer, block_size, output_dir)
    print(f'{metrics=}')
    # - Evluate on whole datasets
    print('---- Evaluate model on Whole OpenWebtext')
    metrics = eval_hf_with_subsample('UDACA/pile_openwebtext2', None, 'validation', model, tokenizer, block_size, output_dir, max_eval_samples=None)
    # eval_hf(trainer=Trainer(model=model, args=eval_args, train_dataset=None, eval_dataset=eval_dataset1))
    print(f'{metrics=}')
    print('---- Evaluate model on Whole C4')
    metrics = eval_hf_with_subsample('c4', 'en', 'validation', model, tokenizer, block_size, output_dir, max_eval_samples=None)
    # eval_hf(trainer=Trainer(model=model, args=eval_args, train_dataset=None, eval_dataset=eval_dataset2))
    print(f'{metrics=}')
    print('Done!\a')

def main():  
    """Since accelerate config wants this, main_training_function: main"""
    train()

# -- Run __main__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'\n\n\n------------------- Running {__file__} -------------------')
    # -- Run tests and time it
    import time
    time_start = time.time()
    # -- Run tests
    main()
    # -- End tests, report how long it took in seconds, minutes, hours, days
    print(f'Time it took to run {__file__}: {time.time() - time_start} seconds, {(time.time() - time_start)/60} minutes, {(time.time() - time_start)/60/60} hours, {(time.time() - time_start)/60/60/24} days\a')
```

related: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/dataset-transform-hangs-indefinitely-while-finetuning-the-stable-diffusion-xl/59938

Answer (score 3):

This message:

> Detected kernel version 5.4.0, which is below the recommended minimum of 5.5.0; this can cause the process to hang. It is recommended to upgrade the kernel to the minimum version

is not referring to the CUDA version, it is referring to the Linux kernel version. Is the training hanging for you? if not, i’d just continue working normally. if it does hang, look for instructions on how to upgrade the *Linux kernel*

Comment: how did you know it was the linux kernel?

Comment: Mostly because current CUDA versions are 11 or 12 (or 10 on very old systems). Also, the discussion you linked refers to a deadlock in the kernel, which is Linux.